# monogame obj + mtl loader with textures

Tags: 3d, xna, xamarin, monogame

How can I load model from wavefront .obj (+mtl + textures) file in MonoGame for Android  project at runtime (model is dynamically generated)? Is any out-of-the box solution (something like Content.Load("myobj.obj"))?

Comment: You're going to want to convert the model to FBX, and then proceed to compile it using the XNA content compiler (create an XNA project in Visual Studio, add the FBX as content, build, and grab the xnb file from the bin folder). Reference this xnb in your monogame project and Content.Load("myobj");

Answer (score 1):

The first, easy way is to convert the model to the standard DirectX format in any model editor and use that through the content pipeline.

If, for whatever reason, you must load it dynamically - it's easier than you think. While you *could* google around and find a pre-made API such as http://assimp.sourceforge.net/ , just look at a `.obj` file in notepad or a similar text editor. Here's a (heavily trimmed) sample:

```
o Cube
v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000
v 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 2/1 3/2 4/3
```

It's a really easy model format! `o` indicates a new mesh, `v` indicates a new vertex, `vt` indicates a texture coordinate, and to put it all together `f` represents a face, created from vertex indices.

With a little work and research, anyone can put together a `.obj` loader for any engine, including XNA. It's one of the easiest model formats to work with.

Comment: The problem is: obj and textures is generating dynamically (runtime) by existing code.

Comment: Both of the methods I mentioned above are fully compatible with reading .obj files at runtime :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently finished writing content pipeline for obj format for my needs.
I can share source code with, but it is for XNA 4.0 and I'm not sure that it is suitable for MonoGame because I never worked with it.